# how to build domains in tableau?

Tags: jasper-reports, tableau-api

`Domains are virtual view of a data source that presents the data in business terms, allows for localization, and provides data-level security. ADomain is a metadata layer that provides a business view of the data accessed through a data source`

this is domain definition as in Jaspersoft reporting tool.

I am currently given the task to build or come with a design to create some domains in tableau.. (like in jaspersoft)

[examples of domains in jaspersoft](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/example-creating-domain-using-virtual-data-source)

In jaspersoft when you click on a domain : ex customer domain: you will see the list of tables (that are selected)

How to do the same in tableau?
Please guide me on this..

Answer (score 1):

The meta data layers in Tableau are quite lightweight compared to other BI tools, which is ofter a plus, but seems to fight against your assigned task.

Usually the best approach in Tableau is to learn to use the tool well, build visualizations for your business domain, test and refine them, and then later focus on factoring out common meta-data as your Tableau projects grow. That tends to work better than insisting on a big meta data design up front approach.

Still as you learn to use Tableau, the features that you'll want to understand related to your question are everything about data connections (which define how to connect to a data source, and the fields, data types, calculations, groups, sets, field roles etc). You can start with a data connection in a single workbook and then save the connection separately (typically on the server) so that it can be shared among multiple workbooks (to reduce duplication). You can also use Tableau Server like a proxy for your database.

For security, you can look into the groups and access controls provided by Tableau Server, along with user filters.

Some of the features you ask about might be more properly relegated to the database server, such as by defining common views visible to different users.

Comment: +1:) i had a similar question .. but say like i created a data source(joining 2-3 tables) and saved the data extract but again if i get new data added to existing tables..will the new data be added to my data extract?

Comment: You can choose either behavior. If you do nothing, the extract will be fixed with the data that you put into the extract when you created it (good when you want to make sure nothing changes underneath your analysis). Or you can refresh the extract to pull in new data, either manually or on an automated schedule. So if you know your data is updated every Friday night, there is no reason to have your visualizations use a live connection. You can gain speed by using an extract, and schedule it to be automatically refreshed every weekend.